# Openlayers Feature Popups

Tags: 7, javascript

I am trying to use the [Openlayers Feature Popups](http://drupal.org/project/olfp) module  for my map.

Just ran into some issues which I am yet to find a solution. Under the behaviors tab of the map I have tried to adjust the settings so that the popup can have the name of the node on the popup all I get is a blank popup on click and .undefined on hover.

How do I get the node title and any other field for that matter to show up on the popup just for a starting point at least.

Answer (score 2):

Did you create a Data Overlay with the fields you need in Views? In Views, when you create a Data Overlay that you decide to later use in your map, you define the fields you want to pull from the node (Title, location, etc.) and then assign them inside the Data Overlay dialogue.